# How tell the compiler to copy a file somewhere else after it is built?

Tags: compilation, c++builder

I have two computers.  One is intended to be left 'free' for high-performance activities (such as playing games) The other is my 'all purpose' computer where I install all the apps I use for creating things, and so on.

On the second computer I use Codegear C++ Builder to work on an app that I use on the first computer.

If I have BCB compile to comp 1 it is hopeless.  It becomes unresponsive.  It compiles locally very quickly.  So what I do is compile locally and then copy the exe to the other machine.

Well,  I'm all for streamlining processes, so I want a way to compile on PC2 and use on PC1 without any intermediate steps.

So is it possible to have BCB do the compiling on PC2 and create a local exe file, then copy the file to PC 1?

Comment: Write a makefile, and have its last action be a file copy.

Comment: If you have a more recent version of C++ Builder, set up the copying as a post-build event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of BCB support creating makefiles from projects which can easily be modified to copy files.
Most versions of BCB support having batch files as part of the project.
The latest versions of BCB have build events which could copy files for you.

Which version of BCB are you using?